# Android: How to produce .WAV file using MediaRecorder class?

Tags: android, audio, wav, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I had some trouble with creating certain file types.

```
 MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
 myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
 myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
```

Can you explain me which one of these I need to use combined in order to produce regular MP3, WAV, AAC or AMR audio files. Now I'm unsure if that's a correct way  :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't produce wav or mp3 using MediaRecorder. Using MediaRecorder you can produce 3gp, aac and m4a. I am using these code blocks to record audio from microphone:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 9) {
        // Android 2.3.2 and lower
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "XXX"
                + File.separator + strDate + ".3gp";
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 15) {
        // Android 2.3.3 - Android 4.0.4
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "XXX"
                + File.separator + strDate + ".m4a";
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    } else {
        // Android 4.1 and above
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "XXX"
                + File.separator + strDate + ".m4a";
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
    }
```

<strike>Note: When I try to produce aac sound that file can't be playable on Android but not playable on Windows. I'm not sure why but m4a is also produce quality sounds.</strike>

Edit: m4a and 3gp files play perfectly on Android 4.x. Particularly I tested on Android 4.4.2 Samsung Galaxy 4.4.2 and both output format play without problem.  However I couldn't play m4a file on Android 5.x and Android 6.x. aac file is doesn't play all three platform. But all files (3gp, m4a, aac) play on Windows 10. I have no idea why.